# Python crash course chapter 18. No learning_log directory is created

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm doing exercises in the 'Python Crash Course' book in Chapter 18. I can't create the learning_log directory and manage.py, **init**.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py files.

I made the creation of a virtual environment with the command:

```
python -m venv ll_env
```

I am using Windows so I used the command to activate the virtual environment:

```
ll_env\Scripts\activate
```

The environment has been activated because the name (ll_env) is displayed before the prompt.
Then I installed the Django framework with the command:

```
pip install django
```

Installed successfully.But when I used the command:

```
django-admin.py startproject learning_log .
```

Unfortunately, the learning_log directory and the previously mentioned files are not created.
I installed django version 3.1.4 and the book is version 2.2. Is there a problem here? Is there any other command to create this directory and files?
Let me add that I was doing it all in the PyCharm terminal.

Comment: try `django-admin startproject learning_log .`

Comment: Thanks! It works! Why did it have to be done like that?

Comment: The command name is `django-admin` according to the documentation.